# Play animation more than once Js

Tags: javascript, animation

im trying to make a little game and im trying to make an animation work, it works but only once.
I tried to delete the class name and recall it on the click but it doesnt work. Somebody some help ?

```
const monstre = document.getElementById('tigrou');
const barreDeVie = document.getElementById('barredevie');
let vie = document.getElementById('vie');
let vieRestante = 10000;
let test = 100;
vie.innerHTML = vieRestante + "/10000";
let barrevie = document.getElementById('oui');
let coups = 0;

monstre.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    monstre.classList.remove("tigrou");
    coups+= 1;
    vieRestante-=1;
    vie.innerHTML = vieRestante + "/10000";
    test -= 0.01;
    barrevie.style.width = test + '%';

    monstre.className +='tigrou';
});
```

Comment: Hey friend, can you add a simple jsfiddle or some snipet that is not working as expected :)

Comment: yeah sure. just look at where the image is usually for the animation 
 https://jsfiddle.net/zk0Lcyas/

Comment: hmmm the image is not shown. Did you forgot to upload the image?